# Using an .sks file to layout a complex object vs a SKScene file

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3, xcode8

Is it possible to use the SceneEditor to layout & create a complex Subclass of SKSpriteNode, load that information and create a custom object in your scene based on the sks file?

My scenario is that I have a popup dialogs (which are nothing more than  subclasses of SKSpriteNodes) with a lot of children on the dialog. I was hoping to lay it out in the Scene editor similar to how I lay out an SKScene, and then present it in my scene when needed.

I realize that I could just create this object in my GameScene.sks file, but find that those can get easily cluttered, and thought it might be a nicer way to store these dialgos if each had their own sks file.

I've tried extending SKSpriteNode to access the file similar to the Scene file but it didn't work

```
if let teamDialog = SKSpriteNode.spriteWithClassNamed(className: "TeamDialog", fileName: "TeamDialog.sks") { }

extension SKSpriteNode {

    static func spriteWithClassNamed(className: String, fileName: String) -> SKSpriteNode? {

        guard let dialog = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: fileName) else {
                return nil
        }

        return dialog
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this delegate https://github.com/ice3-software/node-archive-delegate

Or, smt like this in swift:

```
class func unarchiveNodeFromFile(file:String)-> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {
        var fileData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: fileData)
        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKNode")
        let node = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as SKNode
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return node
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

UPDATE for Swift 3 and fix class casting:

```
func unarchiveNodeFromFile(file:String)-> SKNode? {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: "sks") {
        let fileData = NSData.init(contentsOfFile: path)
        let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver.init(forReadingWith: fileData as Data!)
        archiver.setClass(SKNode.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let node = archiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! SKNode
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return node
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think that this can work. The top node in the sks file is always going to be a SKScene. So, yes using NSKeyedUnarchiver i can get the file as a SKScene, I can then find the child SpriteNode of this unarchived scene but it is already has a parent. And I can't add a scene to a scene.

Comment: You are right, you can't add scene to a scene, but since a SKScene has a SKNode as a super class you can use it and add this object as SKNode. It works for me pretty fine

Comment: I must be missing some key element or casting. I am using the function you supplied, and calling it using     if let wtf = MenuScene.unarchiveNodeFromFile(file: "TeamDialog")! as SKNode? {
            addChild(wtf)
        }  however I am getting an error when adding to the scene 
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Cant add body, already exists in a world', reason: 'Cant add body <SKPhysicsBody> type:<Rectangle> representedObject:[<SKScene> name:'teamDialogScene' frame:{{-768, -1024}, {1536, 2048}} anchor:{0.5, 0.5}], already exists in a world'

Comment: Made fixes for swift 3 and classes casting. The main reason of the error is here `archiver.setClass(SKNode.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")`

Comment: I had already converted it to swift 3 and couldn't add the object to the scene. I'm going to mark this as correct, because technically it answers whether or not I can use the scene editor to layout sprite nodes vs just scenes. However it won't let me add the unarchived object to the scene, so I've created a new question with more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943165/unarchived-node-doesnt-appear-when-added-to-parent-in-spritekit