# Creating a custom initalizer for SKScene that overrides convenience init?(fileNamed:)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3, initialization, xcode8

I'm trying to create a convenience initializer that overrides the `convenience init? (fileNamed:)` initializer in SKScene so that I can pass some initial values to the scene while also unarchiving the .sks file. The problem is that when I try to do this, it seems that the subclass of SKScene (GameScene) is unable to see the `convenience init? (fileNamed:)` of the superclass. Here are some of my attempts:

```
Class GameScene : SKScene {

var stage : Int?

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

convenience init?(fileNamed: String, stage: Int) {
    self.init(fileNamed: fileNamed)  // Compiler error-- Argument labels '(filenamed:)' do not match any available overloads
    self.stage = stage
}
```

Another attempt I found suggested as a workaround:

```
Class GameScene : SKScene {

var stage : Int?

override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

convenience init?(fileNamed: String) {
    self.init(fileNamed: fileNamed) // Error at run time: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16fc1bff0) 
}

convenience init?(fileNamed: String, stage: Int) {
    self.init(fileNamed: fileNamed)  
    self.stage = stage
}
```

The debugger reveals an endless loop of `GameScene.init(fileNamed : String) -> GameScene?`

How do I accomplish this? I need to move on with my life!! (and this project...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't it be as simple as this?

```
if let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

        self.gameScene = gameScene
        self.gameScene.stage = 1
        self.gameScene.setupBasedOnStage()
        self.gameScene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        self.gameScene.gameSceneDelegate = self.menuSceneDelegate as! GameSceneDelegate!
        self.view?.presentScene(self.gameScene, transition: SKTransition.reveal(with: .down, duration: 1.0))
    }
```

You are able to set the stage property before revealing the page, and if you needed to you can call a setup function to load info/graphics based on the stage.

I know it's not as elegant as what you are trying to do, but maybe sometimes the easiest answer is the best?

Comment: Point taken! This does the job. Thanks for being the voice of pragmatism. I would however love to know why I can't seem to successfully override the convenience init in SKScene...

Comment: By the way--what is the GameSceneDelegate type? I've never used that.

Comment: oops, shouldn't have included that in my example...I create my own Delegates on my scenes and I make the GameViewController conform to those delegates. That way if I need the GameViewController to do something (display leaderboards, screenshots, contact/mail dialog, etc.) I just call gameSceneDelegate.showLeaderboards() vs. find the GameViewController, putting it into a variable and then calling the function

Comment: If your interested in using the Scene Editor SKS files, you may want to look at my findings here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943165/unarchived-node-doesnt-appear-when-added-to-parent-in-spritekit What I've started doing is creating complex dialogs in their own scene file and be able to load them when needed as a SKpriteNode Subclass (not a SKScene) from any existing SKScene I want

Comment: Wow, interesting. I'm going to check this out. Thanks!

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html "Rule 2
A convenience initializer must call another initializer from the same class."

Comment: @BrianBroom his convenience initializer was calling another initialize in the same class

Comment: @RonMyschuk - its not the same class. init(fileNamed:) is in (I think)  SKNode

Answer (score 3):

Swift has rules around convenience initializers:

> Rule 1: A designated initializer must call a designated initializer
>   from its immediate superclass.
>
> Rule 2: A convenience initializer must call another initializer from
>   the same class.
>
> Rule 3: A convenience initializer must ultimately call a designated
>   initializer.

The initializer `public convenience init?(fileNamed filename: String)` is itself a convenience initilizer on `SKNode`, so attempting to call it from your own convenience initializer breaks Rule 2.

If you see in the Xcode quick tips, the only initializer available to call from your convenience initializer would be `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` which satisfies Rule 3.

Comment: I see. So is it possible to create a convenience init that combines (fileNamed:) in order to load the .sks as well as other parameters?

Comment: You would have to load the `sks` file yourself, rather than call the (fileNamed:) convenience initilizer.