# How to pass in parameters to SKScene Class and then present the scene, within SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a class 'GameplaySceneClass' which is an ***SKScene*** and I would like to pass parameters to it and then present the scene. The class can be seen below

```
class GameplaySceneClass: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    
    // var level: Float = the passed in level

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        // print(level)
    }
}
```

The presentation of the scene can be seen below within the 'GameViewController'.

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
    if let scene = GameplaySceneClass(fileNamed: "mainGameplayScene") {
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

If I wanted to pass a value for 'level' to be used within the 'GameplaySceneClass', how would I do this?

I have tried using an initializer as can be seen below.

```
class GameplaySceneClass: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var level: Float

    init(level: Float) {
        self.level = level
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder: aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        print(level)
    }
}
```

However I doing so, I was unable to pass in the other paramater 'fileNamed'. How would I be able to do both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find an answer to my question, taken from here [Creating a custom initalizer for SKScene that overrides convenience init?(fileNamed:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209983/creating-a-custom-initalizer-for-skscene-that-overrides-convenience-initfilena)

The code becomes

```
class GameplaySceneClass: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    
     var level: Float?

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

         print(level)
    }
}
```

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
    if let scene = GameplaySceneClass(fileNamed: "mainGameplayScene") {
        scene.level = 1.0
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```