# Rounded rectangle with SKShapeNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have the following code that rounds an already existing rectangle from the scene builder...

```
btOk.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -62.5,y:-25,width: 125, height: 50), cornerRadius: 10).cgPath
```

However, if i try to use the same init to round the corners of another rectangle that is much larger, it does not even come close to working.  It just makes the width HUUUUGE (imagine Trump).

```
scene.enumerateChildNodes(withName: "//*"){
            node,stop in

    if let name = node.name{
        if name.contains("round"){
            if let shapeNode = node as? SKShapeNode{
                print(shapeNode.frame.width) //500
                shapeNode.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -250,y:-100,width: 500, height: 200), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
                print(shapeNode.frame.width) //5735
             }
        }
    }
}
```

`btOk` is a SKShapeNode as well. What am i missing between the two that is so different? One thing to note is i am enumerating through the children of the scene like this because this scene is in a SKReferenceNode.  Perhaps that has something to do with it?

**EDIT**

Taking direction from @Ron Myschuk, i've solved this and since it's such a PITA, i also created an extension. So now i can round the corners of any SKShapeNode very easily when needed.  Even if it was created in the scene editor.  Note, this should only be used if there are no children of the shape node. Otherwise those children will be removed also.

```
extension SKShapeNode {
    func roundCorners(topLeft:Bool,topRight:Bool,bottomLeft:Bool,bottomRight:Bool,radius: CGFloat,parent: SKNode){
        let newNode = SKShapeNode(rect: self.frame)
        newNode.fillColor = self.fillColor
        newNode.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
        newNode.position = self.position
        newNode.name = self.name
        self.removeFromParent()
        parent.addChild(newNode)
        var corners = UIRectCorner()
        if topLeft { corners = corners.union(.bottomLeft) }
        if topRight { corners = corners.union(.bottomRight) }
        if bottomLeft { corners = corners.union(.topLeft) }
        if bottomRight { corners = corners.union(.topRight) }
        newNode.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -(newNode.frame.width / 2),y:-(newNode.frame.height / 2),width: newNode.frame.width, height: newNode.frame.height),byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width:radius,height:radius)).cgPath
    }
}
```

And use it like so...

```
aShapeNode.roundCorners(topLeft: true, topRight: true, bottomLeft: false, bottomRight: false, radius: 5,parent: popup)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not what you're going to want to hear but it's because you cannot set the width of an SKShapeNode in the Scene editor (To my knowledge). In order to get that ShapeNode to have a width of 500 you would have had to adjust the xScale. The xScale then reapplies itself to the path when you adjust it (kind of growing exponentially). If you create the SKShapeNode in code there is no problem adjust the rounded corners

```
    let round = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: -150, width: 500, height: 200))
    round.fillColor = .red
    addChild(round)
    print(round.frame.width)
    round.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -250, y: -100, width: 500, height: 200), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
    print(round.frame.width)
```

> Edit

If you have your heart set on using the Scene editor you can place your ShapeNode and stretch it to where you want it then you could just do a small conversion in code to get the results that you want

```
    if let round = self.childNode(withName: "biground") as? SKShapeNode {

        let biground = SKShapeNode(rect: round.frame)
        biground.fillColor = round.fillColor
        biground.position = round.position
        addChild(biground)
        round.removeFromParent()

        print(biground.frame.width)
        biground.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect(x: -250, y: -100, width: 500, height: 200), cornerRadius: 50).cgPath
        print(biground.frame.width)
    }
```

this just recreates the shape in code based on what you outlined in the Scene editor and rounds the edges perfectly

> edit 2

I've always been under the impression that SKShapeNodes are really inefficient (i'm pretty sure they leaked memory as well). So i always setup my round rectangles as so.

```
    let outsideTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "round_square_white")
    let outside = SKSpriteNode(texture: outsideTexture)      
    let insetX: CGFloat = 20
    let insetY: CGFloat = 20
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: 500.0, height: 500.0)

    outside.centerRect = CGRect(x: CGFloat(insetX / outside.size.width), y: CGFloat(insetY / outside.size.height), width: CGFloat((outside.size.width - insetX * 2) / outside.size.width), height: CGFloat((outside.size.height - insetY * 2) / outside.size.height))
    //outside.position = CGPointMake(gameModel.gameWidth / 2, (outside.size.height) / 2);
    outside.xScale = cellSize.width / outside.size.width
    outside.yScale = cellSize.height / outside.size.height
    outside.zPosition = 10
    outside.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(-0.35 * self.size.height / 2))
    self.addChild(outside)
```

worth noting that this lays out a rounded square/rectangle perfectly however similar to the scale issues from the scene editor you have to place an empty cell over this to add children to, otherwise they scale to the rounded square.

Comment: Lol. You answered my other SpriteKit scene question earlier today.  I like using scene editor but this really becoming a PITA with all the little scale quirks and whatever else I'm going to find.

Comment: I absolutely agree it has a ton of quirks, but I still think it has potential. Right now I am trying to create a game that is solely laid out in the Scene editor, somethings are frustrating but on the whole it is sooooo much faster than laying it out in code, run it, change some values, re-run it, repeat, repeat, repeat

Comment: I like your suggested work around.  Just seems a bit inefficient, but oh well.

Comment: Welcome to Spritekit! where inefficient work around is our middle name!

Comment: You might want to check out my post over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41943165/unarchived-node-doesnt-appear-when-added-to-parent-in-spritekit on creating complex objects in their own scene file, it's really changed how I am developing games right now

Comment: You can also place these complex objects into other scenes in the editor by dragging on a reference node and setting "reference" to your sks file it'll blow your mind at how awesome it is.

Comment: And as always if my advice helps you out please up-vote and mark as correct

Comment: Yes that's what I did here.  These rects are just a portion of a popup window that appears during the game multiple times. So I've setup a sks file as a template and made a function that adds a reference node with the scene file.  I pass all the variables I need for the popup(heading,button texts, etc) to the function and it works like a charm.  I just want my rectangles rounded!!! Lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137085/discussion-between-ron-myschuk-and-thevalyreangroup).

Comment: Checkout my edit, i went the route of your first suggestion, then took it a step further.  Everything works great now.  Thank you sir.